# Color Map for Representing the Three Possible Outcomes

Tags: matplotlib

I'm using the `colormap.YlOrRd` Color Map to shade each polygon (district) on my map, based on the population in that district.

However, what kind of a Color Map would you recommend if I wanted to shade each district based on three possible outcomes - say, Catholic, Presbyterian or Anglican. Or say Conservative, Libertarian or Socialist. Or married, single or divorced. I have 5,000 districts on the map and I don't want to use scatter pie charts.

This is a solution for two possible outcomes:

[image]

Also, lets say two of the outcomes are closely related while the third isn't - for example: The Right Party, Socialist People's Party and Party of Socialist People. Here it would be nice to shade the map so that it is clear whether the Right has a majority in a district or not while still being able to visualise the difference between the two socialist parties.

So lets say my data is organised like this:

> ```
>                    RP SP PS
> Jefferson Urban 1: 30 40 30   
> Jefferson Urban 2: 40 40 20   
> Jefferson Urban 3: 10 30 60   
> Jefferson Urban 4:  5 20 75
> Washington Ward 1: 80  0 20
> Washington Ward 2: 90  5  5
> Lincoln Park West: 10  5 85
> Lincoln Park East: 10  0 90
> ```

Here is one type of three outcome solution I have found:
[image]
where the map is shaded based on the largest party per district. Not exactly what I'm after as you can't get a feel for how each party has performed on a district level. Perhaps its best to have three separate maps for each party.

I'm currently shading each district according to population density as follows:

```
  colormap = cm.YlOrRd
  norm = colors.LogNorm(vmin=(min(population.values())), vmax=(max(population.values()))) 
  sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=colormap, norm=norm)
  sm.set_array([])

  for district in population:
      col = colormap(population[district]) 
      p = PolygonPatch(polygon[district],facecolor=col, edgecolor=col, zorder=2, lw=None, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()) 
      ax.add_patch(p)
```

Comment: The question is pretty general, so the general answer is: Create a colormap with the three colors you would like to see in your plot.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thats the easy part. But what color should it be shaded if its 33%/33%/33%? Or 50%/50%/0% or 0%/50%/50%?